# Firebase passwordless authentication by modifying the emailVerified property?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's `email + password` Auth system.

I have a use case(passwordless auth) where I'd like to verify the user's email a second time.
So assuming they already had their email verified once, I'd like to:

- Send them another "verify your email" Email, i think this would work by simply calling sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion(..)
- After they verify their email a second time, Determine that they did. The first time I can check the emailVerified Boolean, but is there a way to reset this emailVerified Boolean to False and check it a second time?

How can I achieve this?

[Edited]

More description if it helps:

Im trying to do Passwordless Authentication. Maybe this is not possible on Firebase and I'd have to use something like auth0

I have only 2 flows.

**Flow 1: Sign Up**

- Input an email and username (Display name in firebase).
- Verify your email.
- Now you stay signed in until the app is deleted from the phone ( a default password is used to sign you in and sign you out on app open and app exit respectively)

**Flow 2: Login**

- This flow becomes relevant if you have an account with the App, but you deleted it in the past and reinstalled again
- Input your email/username
- if you have an account, you'll get an email to "verify that it is you again"
- Verified? Now you stay signed in until the app is deleted from the phone ( a default password is used to sign you in and sign you out on app open and app exit respectively)

Comment: Isn't flow 2 the same as sending a password reset email (for which I can't find any docs link at the moment)?

Comment: I think yes, it could be done with a password reset email, but the design appears a bit unintended in that case . A user reinstalling an app, might wonder why he would need to reset his password each time. Is this a common way to do Passwordless auth in firebase?

Comment: Not really, our email+password authentication provider is in fact often referred to as Password auth, e.g. in the navigation or URL in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth. It is tightly bound to the concept of having a password for the account. Not requiring a password would constitute a custom authentication provider.

Comment: yeah i figured that and I think i'd have to go with auth0 for a true passwordless system

Comment: Sounds good. If you get it set up, I'm quite sure other developer would love to see how it works for you, either in the answer below or in a blog post somewhere!

Comment: thats, a good idea! I'll post an update of my notes

Answer (score 1):

I dont think a true passwordless email-auth system is possible in Firebase. Im going to instead do this with Auth0

Comment: Firebase Auth now supports passwordless email link sign: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth